# print groupby element in separate lists according to the value of one column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This code prints out the corresponding value of the 'target' variable based on the max level of the variable 'time' for each category 'categ'.
The problem is that it prints them together in the same list, while I would like to have them in separate lists according to the value of 'time'. In this example, the output is `[3, 5, 2, 1, 10, 4]`, when my goal is this: `[3,5],[2],[1,10],[4]`. I hope I have been clear in my explanation. Any hints in how to do it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data=[[1,1,2,2,'A'],
      [2,5,5,1,'A'],
      [3,7,9,4,'B'],
      [1,5,1,9,'B'],
      [1,8,2,8,'C'],
      [2,8,5,10,'C'],
      [0,1,2,3,'D'],
       [1,1,1,2,'E'] ,
        [0,1,1,5,'F']]
    

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time','x','y','target','categ'])

res_target = df.loc[df.groupby('categ')['time'].transform('max').eq(df['time']), ['time', 'target']].sort_values('time')['target']
print(res_target.values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Fix your code by adding an additional `groupby` on `time`

```
m = df.groupby('categ')['time'].transform('max').eq(df['time'])
target_list = df[m].groupby('time')['target'].agg(list).tolist()
```

---

```
print(target_list)

[[3, 5], [2], [1, 10], [4]]
```